# Django Logging is not working in a module

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

Project Structure:

```
|-project_root
    |- app1
        |- starter.py
        |- submitter.py
        |- management
            |- commands
                |- submitter.py
                |- starter.py

    |- app2
    |- project
        |- settings.py
```

settings.py

```py
...
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'formatters': {
        'detailed': {
            'format': '%(asctime)s [%(levelname)s] %(filename)s:%(lineno)d - %(message)s'
        },
        'simple': {
            'format': '%(levelname)s - %(filename)s - %(lineno)d - %(message)s'
        },
        'time': {
            'format': '%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(message)s'
        },
        'bare': {
            'format': '%(message)s'
        }
    },
    'handlers': {
        'stream': {
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'formatter': 'detailed',
        }
    },
    'loggers': {
        '<project name>': {
            'handlers': ['stream'],
            'level': 'INFO',
            'propagate': True,
        }
    }
}
```

starter.py

```py
import logging
# other imports

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

def starter_func():
    logger.info("starter")
    return
```

submitter.py

```py
import logging
# other imports

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

def submit():
    logger.info("submit")
    return
```

commands:
starter.py

```py
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand

from app1.starter import starter_func


class Command(BaseCommand):
    help = ""

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        starter_func()
```

submitter.py

```py
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand

from app1.submitter import submit


class Command(BaseCommand):
    help = ""

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        submit()
```

when I run python manage.py submitter, it prints logs.
But when I run python manage.py starter, it doesn't print logs.

I tried printing logger.disabled, for submitter it's False, but for starter it is True.

Update:
If I directly use logging in starter, it works!

```
import logging
# other imports

logger = logging

def starter_func():
    logger.info("starter")
    return
```

If I import submit function in starter, logger works!

```
import logging
# other imports
from app1.submitter import submit

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

def starter_func():
    logger.info("starter")
    return
```

What is causing this?

Comment: you sure you have `__init__.py` in every folder?

Comment: Django doesn't require you to add __init__.py in management->commands->/
rest have __init__.py